# UNIX command to dereference a symbolic link?

Tags: unix, shell

Is there a `UNIX` command to dereference a symbolic link? I would like to replace the link by a copy of the file it points to.

Example:

```
$ ls
a
b -> a

$ deref b
$ ls 
a
b
```

Now, a and b have the same content but are independent of each other. My question is if there is such a `deref` command. Important:  I don't have to know where `b` points to; the command should figure that out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `readlink` to find out the filename, but you don't have to!

```
cp b c
mv c b
```

It's that simple. If you are writing a script to do that, you should use
the output of `mktemp` instead of `c` to make sure you don't override already existing file
`c`.

Answer (score 5):

Combining both answers leads to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -h "$1" ] ; then
  target=`readlink $1`
  rm "$1"
  cp "$target" "$1"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible by copying whatever the symlink points to...

see [readlink(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) and [cp(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp). **Update**: and while you're at it: [readlink(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readlink.html).

**BUT** a symlink is really just that, a symbolic (read: by means of the name of the target) link to another file - it does not share the content of the other file. (hardlink, anyone?).

Answer (score 0):

There's no such command, but you can do the following:

```
rm b
cp a b
```

Comment: That's not ideal because I have to know where `b` points to. I'd like to avoid having to find that out myself.